# I need help loading a file symfony2, cant found the input name in formbuilder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I am following a guide of uploading files in Symfony 2.8

This is my controller.

```php
public function new1Action(Request $request)
{
    $pedido = new Pedidos();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PedidosType, $pedido);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $image = $request->files->get('name_input_image');
        print_r($image);exit;
        if(($image instanceof UploadedFile) && ($image->getError() == '0'))
        {
            $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $name_array = explode('.',$originalName);
            $file_type = $name_array[sizeof($name_array) - 1];
            $valid_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
            if(in_array(strtolower($file_type), $valid_filetypes))
            {
                $document = new Document();
                $document->setFile($image);
                $document->setSubDirectory('archivos');
                $document->processFile();

                $pedido->setDescripcion($image->getBasename());

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($pedido);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                            'Se inserto la imagen correctamente');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bd_pedidos'));

            } else
            {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                            'La extension del archivo no es la correcta');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bd_formnew1'));
            } 
        } else
        {

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('mensaje',
                            'No ingreso el archivo o se produjo un error inesperado');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bd_formnew1'));
        }   
    }
```

The problem is in line `$image = $request->files->get('name_input_image');`
The `'name_input_image'` is the name of the input in my view. When i try to use a regular input (without formbuilder) everything works well because I can control the name of my input, but when I use formbuilder I don't know what is the name of the input which should be set in `$image = $request->files->get('XXXXX');` .

I also tried with `{{ form.task.vars.full_name }}` this can return `pedido_bdbundle_pedidos[descripcion]`, but when I use `$image = $request->files->get('pedido_bdbundle_pedidos[descripcion]');` my `$image` variable is empty.

I don't know where the problem is or what I can do.

This is my view:

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{path('bd_formnew1')}}">
<table class="record_properties">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.codArticulo) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.codArticulo) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.descripcion) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.descripcion) }}</td> // this is my image field
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.abreviacion) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.abreviacion) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.color) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.color) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.cantidad) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.cantidad) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.precio) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.precio) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.envio) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.envio) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.total) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.total) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.fechaIni) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.fechaIni) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.fechaFin) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.fechaFin) }}</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label (form.flag) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget (form.flag) }}</td>
    </tr>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Maybe the problem is in my entity. Does anyone know how can I set the name of my input file in form builder?

This is my entity:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('codArticulo',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('descripcion',FileType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px'),'label'=>'Imagen', 'data_class'=>null))
            ->add('abreviacion',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('color',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('cantidad',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('precio',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('envio',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('total',TextType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px')))
            ->add('fechaIni',DateType::class, array('widget'=>'single_text', 'html5' => false, 'input' => 'datetime','label'=>'Fecha Pedido','format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy', 'read_only'=>true, 'attr'=> ['class'=>'form-control js-datepicker', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px','placeholder'=>'dd/mm/yyyy']))
            ->add('fechaFin',DateType::class, array('widget'=>'single_text', 'html5' => false, 'input' => 'datetime','label'=>'Fecha Entrega','format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy', 'read_only'=>true, 'attr'=> ['class'=>'form-control js-datepicker', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px','placeholder'=>'dd/mm/yyyy']))
            ->add('flag',ChoiceType::class, array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:5px'),'disabled'=>false,'choices'=>array('1'=>'Vigente','0'=>'Arrivado'),'required'=>true))
            ;
}
```

Comment: Not quite the proper solution, but an easy fix: Just get all the files form the $request->files method. And then get the first entry in that array. No need to fetch it by name if your form only contains one file upload field anyway.

Comment: Another solution would be, to get the file from the form model after the form has been submitted. So in this case from your $pedido variable.

Comment: Also, just a side remark: Symfony supports a MimeTypeChecker which you should use to check for proper mime types on a file. Also, you can and should set a validation constraint on your form field to only support files of that mime type. That would be way more secure and stable than what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to submit your form in your controller action with `$form->handleRequest`:

```
public function new1Action(Request $request)
{
    $pedido = new Pedidos();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PedidosType, $pedido);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $image = $pedido->getImage();
        //
```

`handleRequest()` will hydrade your `Pedido` object with the request data via the form.

Now that your `$pedido` object is hydrated you can directly retrieve the image with the getter that you've set in your entity class.

Comment: U r amazing... 2 days lost with this problem... Now all its ok... I will find out how to give you 5 stars... thanks

Comment: Just accept and upvote the answer that's the best you can do to reward me.Glad it helped